# GitHub: LICENSE.txt: No such file or directory

Tags: git, github, windows-7

I am new to GitHub, and I wanted to host my code on github by creating a repository. So, I followed the below steps:

1. Created a remote repository using GitHub
2. Created a local repository using "git init" command to my local project directory
3. Added files using "git add filename/foldername" command then all the other folders/files were getting added but when I tried adding "node_modules" folder of my project, I got this error:

   ```
   fatal: unable to stat 'node_modules/karma/node_modules/gruntconventionalchangelog/node_modules/conventionalchangelog/node_modules/lodash.assign/node_modules/lodash._basecreatecallback/node_modules/lodash._setbinddata/node_modules/lodash.noop/LICENSE.txt': No such file or directory
   ```

Note: I was able to add all the other folders/files by executing same command.

Please help me out with this stuff. I searched on web, but was unable to find the exact solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a reference/location bug. In general you shouldn't add `node_modules` to your repository, since your dependencies should be installed every time with `npm install`. Try re-creating the repository and leaving `node_modules` out.

Comment: Leaving node_modules, am already able to add all other files/folders.. But what if I want to add "node_modules" ?

Comment: It's difficult to tell where exactly the problem is. Could you isolate all the non-sensitive files and the package.json and put them on Github or Gist? Also, can you specify your OS?

Comment: May be this can be a reason: 
In the Windows API, the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is defined as 260 characters.

Comment: That could be it, I've had issues with very long file names under Windows before. This also points to why `node_modules` shouldn't be added to the repo: it could lead to a very deep hierarchy with long file names.